# Why do we use the "salt" to secure our passwords?

Tags: encryption

i was reading [this tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-and-viewing-users-two#sec:secure_passwords), and i encountered the following discussion about encryption. At the end there's written

> **In the last line, we’ve hashed the salt with the password, yielding an
>   encrypted password that is virtually
>   impossible to crack**

But in my opinion an hacker who has both the `encrypted_password` and the `salt` could do the "rainbow" trick exactly as if we were using the `salt`.

So, where i'm wrong?

Thanks!

> ```
> $ rails console
> >> require 'digest'
> >> def secure_hash(string)
> >>   Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(string)
> >> end
> => nil
> >> password = "secret"
> => "secret"
> >> encrypted_password = secure_hash(password)
> => "2bb80d537b1da3e38bd30361aa855686bde0eacd7162fef6a25fe97bf527a25b"
> >> submitted_password = "secret"
> => "secret"
> >> encrypted_password == secure_hash(submitted_password)
> => true
> ```
>
> Here we’ve defined a function called
>   secure_hash that uses a cryptographic
>   hash function called SHA2, part of the
>   SHA family of hash functions, which we
>   include into Ruby through the digest
>   library.7 It’s not important to know
>   exactly how these hash functions work;
>   for our purposes what’s important is
>   that they are one-way: there is no
>   computationally tractable way to
>   discover that
>
> 2bb80d537b1da3e38bd30361aa855686bde0eacd7162fef6a25fe97bf527a25b
>   is the SHA2 hash of the string
>   "secret".
>
> If you think about it, though, we
>   still have a problem: if an attacker
>   ever got hold of the hashed passwords,
>   he would still have a chance at
>   discovering the originals. For
>   example, he could guess that we used
>   SHA2, and so write a program to
>   compare a given hash to the hashed
>   values of potential passwords:
>
> ```
> >> hash = "2bb80d537b1da3e38bd30361aa855686bde0eacd7162fef6a25fe97bf527a25b"
> >> secure_hash("secede") == hash
> => false
> >> secure_hash("second") == hash
> => false
> >> secure_hash("secret") == hash
> => true
> ```
>
> So our attacker has a match—bad news
>   for any users with password "secret".
>   This technique is known as a rainbow
>   attack.
>
> To foil a potential rainbow attack, we
>   can use a salt, which is a different
>   unique string for each user.8 One
>   common way to (nearly) ensure
>   uniqueness is to hash the current time
>   (in UTC to be time zone–independent)
>   along with the password, so that two
>   users will have the same salt only if
>   they are created at exactly the same
>   time and have the same password. Let’s
>   see how this works using the
>   secure_hash function defined in the
>   console above:
>
> ```
> >> Time.now.utc
> => Fri Jan 29 18:11:27 UTC 2010
> >> password = "secret"
> => "secret"
> >> salt = secure_hash("#{Time.now.utc}--#{password}")
> => "d1a3eb8c9aab32ec19cfda810d2ab351873b5dca4e16e7f57b3c1932113314c8"
> >> encrypted_password = secure_hash("#{salt}--#{password}")
> => "69a98a49b7fd103058639be84fb88c19c998c8ad3639cfc5deb458018561c847"
> ```
>
> **In the last line, we’ve hashed the salt with the password, yielding an
>   encrypted password that is virtually
>   impossible to crack**. (For clarity,
>   arguments to hashing functions are
>   often separated with --.)

Comment: A duplicate of a number of other questions on SO.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does using a salt make a pw more secure if it is stored in the db?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005826/how-does-using-a-salt-make-a-pw-more-secure-if-it-is-stored-in-the-db)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Rainbow tables are expensive to compute. Without the salt, you can build a rainbow table once that can be used repeatedly, since the password "password" will always yield the same hash (md5=5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99, sha1=5baa61e4c9b93f3f0682250b6cf8331b7ee68fd8) and is thus easy to identify in a password database.

With a salt, you have to compute a rainbow table for each salt you encounter. A good-sized salt, say 32 bits (ideally, 128 or even more), means you have to compute a rainbow table for every password you want to crack, thus largely defeating its purpose.

Comment: But how do you compare the passwords later without also saving the random salt? If the salt is random, there is no way to know what it was without keep track of it, like saving it in your database. So if someone has the DB, they also have the salt! If someone has access to your DB, they probably also have access to your code too, so they could look and see what salt you use also!

Comment: @Chloe: You save the salt along with the password. I usually break it up and insert the parts into the hash at predetermined (unpublished) locations, just to sow a little extra confusion for the hacker to contend with. But even if the hacker manages to isolate the salt, they still can't, in general, use rainbow tables for the reasons stated in my answer.

Comment: @Chloe: On another note, your point about having the code is incorrect. The most common way means of data theft is SQL injection attacks, which allow the thief to steal pretty much anything contained in the database, but generally doesn't provide access to code in the business layer. I'm not suggesting that code can't also be stolen — it can — but it's much more difficult, and one needn't presume that stolen data means stolen code.

Comment: @Chloe: And this isn't a trivial point. If you assume that stolen data = stolen code, you wouldn't bother obfuscating how the salt is mixed with the password, and then, when it turns out that only your data was stolen, you wouldn't have the additional benefit of the hacker not knowing how to discover the salt.

Comment: I don't believe salt is as important as it once was, nor rainbow tables. [Anatomy of a hack: How crackers ransack passwords like “qeadzcwrsfxv1331”](http://arstechnica.com/security/2013/05/how-crackers-make-minced-meat-out-of-your-passwords/)

Comment: @Chloe: qeadzcwrsfxv1331 is a terrible password. It's a highly regular pattern on a qwerty keyboard. Every password they cracked was flawed. All you could possibly glean from that article is that salts won't turn bad passwords into good passwords (which isn't news). It doesn't invalidate their use.

Comment: Cannot edit comments! "But the thing about salting is this: it slows down cracking only by a multiple of the number of unique salts in a given list. That means the benefit of salting diminishes with each cracked hash. By cracking the weakest passwords as quickly as possible first (an optimization offered by Hashcat) crackers can greatly diminish the minimal amount of protection salting might provide against cracking."

Comment: @Chloe: Sure, from a hacker's perspective, weak passwords will tumble early, reducing the work ahead of them, but that doesn't mean strong passwords are just around the corner. A unique salt for each password means starting from scratch for every single one, and strong passwords occupy an intractably large space (by definition). Without a salt, rainbow tables built on millions of CPU hours would bring orders of magnitude more passwords into their dragnet.

Comment: @Chloe: Incidentally, I agree that rainbow tables aren't as important as they once were, but that's because developers have learned to salt their passwords. If everyone stopped salting passwords, you can bet your bottom dollar that rainbow tables would suddenly become exceedingly popular.

Comment: yeah but if you know the salt you can create a new rainbow table, isn't it?

Comment: @gio: The second paragraph of my answer addresses this.

Answer (score 8):

Salt is to stop someone from pre-computing a "reverse" lookup table that allows an attacker to quickly find a password that results in the target hash. Creating one of these tables is as much work, computationally, as brute-forcing the target password space, so it's only worthwhile if you can use the table on many targets.

Salt prevents this; the attacker would need to account for the salt when they generated the table, so the table would be good for only a single target, and the attacker is back to brute force.

Comment: more than double I would say (for each bit added), you can position the slat typically at the start, end or middle of your strings if the hacker is serious about hacking, he would have to compensate for at least slat in the beginning and end hence probably tripling the storage space required.

Comment: +1, the second sentence of the first paragraph is the key observation.

Comment: @erickson: yeah but since salt is public he can create a new rainbow table isn't it? (the attacker)

Comment: @gio Why would he want to do that?

Comment: @erickson: i meant the attacker. It is claimed salt is used to make harder for attacker to precompute some tables. But as soon as he knows the salt he can then precompute the table again

Comment: @gio Who claims that "salt is used to make harder for attacker to precompute some tables?" My claim is that creating a rainbow table is more work than a dictionary attack, but provides no additional benefit to the attacker when the password is salted. That's why attackers don't create rainbow tables for salted passwords.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are right, if somebody had knowledge of your algorithm and the salt, he could generate a rainbow table. However, generating a rainbow table takes a long time the more characters are allowed.

So for example, if you have an password consisting of 10 characters, which all are numbers, you have 10^10 possibilites. If you allow lower and upper case alphabetical chars, this goes up to 62^10 possibilites, a mere 8.39 * 10^17 permutations; and that's only for 10 character passwords, you also have to take into account any length below that and above, depending on the length of password you allow.

It takes a long time generate such a table, while rainbow tables for the algorithm itself might be readily available, the salt modifies the algorithm to make it your own, and the possibility for a table existing for that is very low.

Comment: Good explanation. From what I understand, it basically just makes the password longer to decrease the probability of guessing it.

Comment: Not really. It doesn't change the password, in the ideal case it would take exactly the same amount of time to brute force it, salted or not. The salt is a defensive mechanism if the attacker has the database. If you use a known algorithm, chances are there is a database of clear-text:hash mappings readily available. If you manipulate the clear text before hashing, these tables become useless, you'd need to generate a table for each salt. If you have a salt for every password in your database, you'd need to generate a table for each password.

Answer (score 2):

If you use salt (even if it is public but uniqueto a site) you will get a protection from hash-dictionaries, where often used passwords are already hashed.

If your salt is secure then they can not brute-force it using supercomputers. They have to check every possible password with your server (which let's hope has some form of bruteforce-protection).

Comment: If the have the hash value and salt, they can try to brute-force it on their own systems, so brute force protection on your servers will do nothing against this class of attack (when they've got your login information).  We can safely assume they can get the algorithm.

Comment: @vbence: You don't use a single salt at a site. You use a different salt for each password.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I have written, public salt only protects against dictionaries, secret salt protects against them doing the cracking on their own system. - I'm not talking about hacking scenarios when they might get your salting algorythm together with your data.

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos I avoided that topic in my post as it can be the subject of a longer conversation I'd happily participate in.

Comment: @vbence: A fixed salt is weaker than a per-password salt. I don't how much discussion there is to be had on that topic.

Comment: Just like erickson said, if you use salt (any salt, specific to your site) then the dictionary has to be specially made for your site. If you include the username in the salt too then the dictionary has to be created for that single user, so it is not even a dictionary any more. Thanks for testing me, and as I said I'm looking forward to our conversation in an earlier hour.