# What stops an attacker from extracting the salt from a BCrypt hashed password?

Tags: hash, bcrypt, salt

My understanding from my initial reading of how BCrypt hashes passwords is that it:

- takes the raw string
- hashes it using a random salt
- appends that salt to the end of the hash (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6832628)

Then when verifying a supplied password, it:

- takes the supplied password
- retrieves the hashed password
- finds the salt from the end of the hashed password
- hashes the supplied password using the salt from the stored password
- checks whether the two are the same

My question is - if the salt is appended to the hashed password, what stops a human from **a)** finding it and **b)** potentially using it to brute-force finding a password ? Does it not negate the benefit of having a random salt rather than a known, but not stored, one?

Comment: Nothing, the salt is not there to prevent brute forcing a password. The salt is there to prevent precomputing a huge table of hashed passwords aka a "rainbow table". [Here](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) is a good tutorial.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we use the "salt" to secure our passwords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252943/why-do-we-use-the-salt-to-secure-our-passwords)